# What happened to Goland's confirm before restarting the debugged program?

Tags: goland

I am using Goland 2021.3.3. In older versions it used to pop up a confirmation box if a run configuration was already running when the Debug or Run button was pressed. Having been using VS for about 20 years, where the green right arrow meant Continue, I keep hitting it when I mean F9 and losing the place in the debugger. Can this warning a setting I can re-enable or has it just been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Preferences/Settings | Advanced Settings | Confirm rerun with process termination*.